# Can't make nginx and php-fpm dockers communicate

Tags: php, nginx, docker

I have created two docker images to match my needs, here is the nginx one:

```
FROM alpine:3.3
RUN apk add --update nginx
EXPOSE 80 443
CMD nginx -c /www/dev/nginx/conf/nginx.conf -g 'daemon off;'
```

then the php-fpm

```
FROM php:7.0-fpm
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates dcmtk libgdcm-tools wkhtmltopdf libdbd-freetds libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libpng12-dev \
&& docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mcrypt \
&& docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
&& docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
RUN apt-get install -y imagemagick --fix-missing
RUN apt-get clean
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
WORKDIR /www/public
CMD rm /etc/freetds.conf
ADD freetds.conf /etc/freetds.conf
CMD rm /var/cache/apk/*
```

Then the run commands in the following order

```
docker create -p 9000:9000 --name php -v /www:/www:rw php
docker start php
docker create --privileged=true -p 80:80 -p 443:443 --name nginx -v /www:/www --link php:php nginx
docker start nginx
```

So far all works good, containers are running and I can even get static content from nginx owever any php script fails with

```
[error] 6#0: *3 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.17.0.1, server: platform.v2.vetology.net, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.17.0.2:9000", host: "localhost.localdomain"
```

doing

```
cgi-fcgi -bind -connect 127.0.0.1:9000
```

from the host machine works and php responds so I know both containers ar working and responsive they just don't communicate.

I read in a different thread that the issue is caused by php and nginx using a different root directory but here is not the case as both have the /www directory mounted and /www/public contains the index.php file I am trying to open.

And here is the nginx.conf

```
    user nobody;
error_log /www/dev/nginx/log/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /www/dev/nginx/log/access.log  main;
    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    gzip  on;
    ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
 include /www/dev/nginx/conf/upstream.conf;
 server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 default ipv6only=on;
  listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
  ssl_certificate     /www/dev/ssl/certificate.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /www/dev/ssl/key.key;
  ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
  root /www/public;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;
  server_name hostname.net;
  location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  }
  client_body_buffer_size    128k;
  client_body_temp_path /www/dev/nginx/tmp/client_body_temp;
  proxy_temp_path   /www/dev/nginx/tmp/proxy_temp_path;
  fastcgi_temp_path  /www/dev/nginx/tmp/fastcgi_temp_path;
  location ~ \.php$ {
   try_files $uri /index.php =404;
   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
   fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
   fastcgi_pass vetology;
   fastcgi_index index.php;
   include fastcgi_params;
  }
 }
}
```

Any ideas of what I maybe doing wrong?

Comment: @zaph will that fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'm not sure you want to start the nginx container with `privileged`. There's also no need to mount the php directive with the `:rw` switch. `rw` is the default mode.

Second, take a look at where you're telling nginx to send the php request -- specifically, which host, which is defined in nginx's `fastcgi_pass` directive. You have it sending the php request to a machine named `vetology`. But docker is linking the containers together with `--link php:php`. That means its taking the container named `php` and giving it the alias named `php`. That means it will be exposed to your nginx container as a machine named `php`.

You can try this out:

```
docker run -it --rm --link php:some_php nginx sh -c 'ping some_php'
```

Change

```
fastcgi_pass vetology;
```

to:

```
fastcgi_pass php:9000;
```

And your container should work.

For complex container assemblies like this one, have a look at docker-compose next.